# GPS - Tracking Accuracy - ( with PHP Geo Plugins / HTML5 / JavaScript )

Tags: javascript, php, html, gps

I Need Help currently I am Developing PHP - Web Application GPS-Tracking.

I used GeoPlugin link: https://www.geoplugin.com/webservices | PHP version and I also try JSON and JavaScript Format but still not accurate. Here is my task.

When I use Geo Plugin with Fiber Internet Connection which is only available in our local City and Other Format to get coordinates it returns to me accurate "Latitude and Longitude" But When I use Mobile Internet Data Geo Plugin and other Formats such as HTML5 / JavaScript / JSON return to me wrong "Latitude and Longitude" but When I use my Mobile Data Connection to existing mobile application GPS its return to me accurate "Latitude and Longitude",

I am really wondering where is the problem?

The Sad thing is our Sales Representative work outside of our office only use Mobile Data Internet Connection my Project is Create GPS Tracking to locate the current position of our staff because of our Sales Representative work outside the office we need to locate their current position/Location. As I told earlier The accuracy will return only USING Fiber Connection but wondering the existing mobile GPS application work correctly return accurate "Latitude and Longitude" using My Mobile Data Internet Connection

Geo Plugins is enough and perfect for What I need but I have encounter problems using Mobile Internet Data Is there anything that I forgot or Missing??

For Testing Link:
https://www.gpslib.andali.ph/new/

With that link other version or format is included such as HTML5/ JavaScript and Geo Plugins which only work accurately When I use Fiber but return me NOT accurate When I use Mobile Data Connection but as I said earlier When I use my mobile data connection to existing mobile apps GPS it works accurately.

Can you help me to solve and figure out the problem? I did search and read the article on google and here but still I got a problem Have you a recommendation or Can you help me solve this?

Comment: Instead of relying on a third party, you could use the [Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API) in the browser itself?

Comment: Yes, I did, as I said I am wondering about the problem I was encounter I mentioned above regarding to accuracy and internet connection between Fiber and Mobile Data Internet Connection even other format isn't accurate ... by the way HTML5 suddenly work now correctly.